# Jsoup - How treat elements which aren't found

Tags: java, jsoup

When Jsoup isn't able to find an element, then I get an exception and the program gets terminated. I would like to have a way to ignore it, when the element can't be found, so that the program keeps running.

I tried the following way:

```
Element contactHtml = null;
String person = "";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
try {
    contactHtml = doc.select("p.initial-contact").get(0);
    person = contactHtml.text();
}  finally {}
```

But the program gets still terminated, when the element isn't there. Is there a way to create code, that simply ignores non-existing elements?

Comment: What is the exception and where is it coming from? *YOU* need to check if `p.initial-contact` returned anything useful before you call `.get(0)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Element contactHtml = null;
String person = "";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

Elements elements = doc.select("p.initial-contact");
if(!elements.isEmpty()) {
   contactHtml = elements.get(0);
   person = contactHtml.text();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you try to access a listindex that doesn't exsist like there is no element at index 0 in your example you are getting a IndexOutOfBoundException. Using a try/catch construct could avoid is Exception but I wouldnt use a "let-it-crash" concept. Instead I would check if there is a actually a tag that with is name.